# Never ending for() and while() loops

Tags: php, mysql

I'm really sorry if this has been asked before, I've looked as far as I could on here and none of the similar questions answer mine...

I'm trying to create a raffle of sorts... I have a database table of members and their entries and I'm trying to insert their names into another database table repeatedly for as many times as their individual entry amounts say.

Now I've looked up for() loops and as far as I can understand it, this attempt of my code should have worked:

```
$Amount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reapingbowl WHERE userid = $reapablef->id") or die(mysql_error());


$reapablef = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
  $reapablef = mysql_fetch_object($reapablef);
 $amount = $reapablef->entries

for($e = 1; $e < $amount; $e++)
{ 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reapingbowl (userid) VALUES ($reapablef->id)") or 
die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Wherein `$amount` is previously defined to pull the entry amounts from the database and `$reapablef` is previously defined to pull the specific user from the database table. The whole thing is wrapped in a while loop that works on one user at a time.

My problem is only that this for() loop never ends. It should, as far as I understand it, end after the amount of entries supersedes the $e value, but it just keeps going and I don't understand why... I have a similar problem with another for() loop and I don't understand why.

I tried a while loop as well with the coding being this:

```
$Amount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reapingbowl WHERE userid = $reapablef->id") or die(mysql_error());


while ($amount = mysql_num_rows($Amount), $amount < $ENTRIES)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reapingbowl (userid) VALUES ('$reapablef->id')") or
die(mysql_error());
}
```

This does the same thing, just keeps going with entering the names neverendingly... I'm really sorry if I'm being stupid or something but please can someone help me figure out why?

Hope that's all the code necessary. All I really want to know is why the for() loop doesn't end ever... (I've tried it somewhere else with the limit of 10 and it still just went on forever)

Comment: How do you know it never ends?

Comment: Could you `var_dump()` `$amount`? Before your for loop add `var_dump($amount)` .

Comment: Do you ever set $amount anywhere?  You need to be updating it for $e to be equal to or greater than it

Comment: Well for one the website stops responding after a while after loading and the database table of entries has a bazillion entries where it was empty before :p and I'll edit in the query for $amount, one sec

Comment: @Elizabeth If `$amount` did not exist that was your problem. Check your php error log too because it may have some useful info.

Comment: Also be careful that `$amount` is a int and not a string.

Comment: Could you post the part of your code in which `$amount` is defined?

Comment: Amount existed before, I forgot to copy that far up, sorry about that!

Comment: `$amount` is not an integer, thus your condition fails in terms of that the evaluation of `$amount` seems always to be bigger than `$e`.

Comment: Ahhh! Not to seem too much of an idiot but how could I make it an integer?

Comment: oh I have used var_dump and the result comes up as "int(5)"? 5 being the amount of entries for that person

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I converted $amount to an int using intval, which worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is, your `$amount` variable contains an object.

As [PHP manual states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), when using comparison operators, an object is always considered greater than a number.

In an alternate reality, PHP could throw a warning at you for doing silly comparisons, but for some reason in this universe of ours it doesn't.

It is well possible there is a simple explanation and/or a good reason for that, but right now I can't think of any.